# Why is foreach not transparent?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Let us consider the following code. Why doesn't the part of the path generated by foreach look the same as the unrolled part?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        edge/.style = {
            draw,
            thick, 
        },
        open/.style = {
            draw, 
            circle, 
            thick, 
            inner sep = 0.09cm, 
        }, 
        closed/.style = {
            open,
            fill,
        }, 
    ]

    \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 5} {
        \node[closed] at (\x, 0) (c\x) {};
        \node[open] at (\x + 0.5, 1) (o\x) {};
    }

    \node at (0.25, 0.5) (start) {$\cdots$};
    \node at (6.25, 0.5) (end) {$\cdots$};

    \path[edge] (start.east) foreach \x in {1, 2, 3} {-- (c\x) -- (o\x)}  -- (c4) -- (o4) -- (c5) -- (o5) -- (end.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This has been around a few times in this site. When nodes are connected they are connected on their border.

Comment: @percusse: But why is there a difference between using foreach or not?

Comment: one of them is a contionus path, the other one is from one node to the other separate paths

Comment: @percusse: Is there a way to build a continuous path with foreach?

Comment: Can you add also the result that you want to make it look like ?

Comment: @percusse: I want the result of continuous path: `\path[edge] (start.east) -- (c1) -- (o1) … (o5) -- (end.west);`. It just seemed stupid to write such path by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\foreach` adds a group level around the loop body. Therefore, I think, the information that the last point was the open circle node gets lost and TikZ connects the line to the end point of the latest drawn line.

There are many ways to use `\foreach` here, because the lines are not really connected. Examples:

```
\path[edge]
  (start.east) -- (c1)
  \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 5} {
    (c\x) -- (o\x)
    \ifnum\x<5
      -- (c\the\numexpr\x + 1\relax)
    \fi
  }
  (o5) -- (end.west)
;
```

or

```
\path[edge]
  (start.east) -- (c1)
  \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 5} {
    (c\x) -- (o\x)
  }
  \foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 4} {
    (o\x) -- (c\the\numexpr\x + 1\relax)
  }
  (o5) -- (end.west)
;
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: You can also use `\draw[thick](start.east) -- (c1) foreach\x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially 1)] in {2,...,5} {(c\lastx) -- (o\lastx)-- (c\x)}  (c5) -- (o5) -- (end.west);`

Comment: So we have to explicitly add both the starting node and the ending node to the body of the loop – this is possible with using the `\the\numexpr\x + 1\relax` syntax I wasn't aware of. Because of the loop body working as a closed interval rather than half-closed, handling the corner cases is more cumbersome.

Comment: @user87690 The handling of the corner cases could be simplified by using the names `(o0)` and `(c6)` for `(start.east)` and `(end.west)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together the following parametrized variant.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.12cm]
    \def \N {5}

    \foreach \i in {1, ..., \N} {
        \node[closed] (c\i) at (\i + 0.25, -0.5) {};
        \node[open] (o\i) at (\i + 0.75, 0.5) {};
    }
    \path[edge] foreach \i in {1, ..., \N} {
        (\i, 0) -- (c\i) -- (o\i) -- (\i + 1, 0)
    };

    \node[anchor=east] at (1 - 0.1, 0) {${\cdots}$};
    \node[anchor=west] at (\N + 1 + 0.1, 0) {${\cdots}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```